# Setting document.title doesn't change the tab's text after pressing back in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

In a single page application I'm in `routeA` with `document.title` set to `"titleA"`.

I then get an in-app notification so the app sets `document.title` to `"titleB"`, and it's reflected in the Chrome browser tab.

I then press the notification and the app goes to `routeB`, still with `"titleB"`.

I mark the notification as read and change `document.title` back to `"titleA"`. This changes correctly.

The problem is when I press the browser's back button: it goes to `routeA`, but it shows `"titleB"` on the tab. If I read `document.title` on Chrome devtools, it shows `"titleA"` (the correct title). The tab doesn't seem to be reflecting `document.title`.

Is there any solution for this? It seems to be a Google Chrome bug, since it doesn't happen in Firefox. Maybe cache or service worker related?

Even if I set the `document.title` manually in devtools, the tab's text doesn't change anymore unless I refresh the page.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the issue by settings `document.title` to something else right before setting the `document.title` to what I want, like so:

```
document.title = "";
document.title = "My title";
```

and also calling this code after the browser completed the "history back" operation (so I listen to the history and set the title again).

It seems to be a bug in Chrome, that for some reason reverts back to the document.title, so still no idea why it happens and why there's nothing online about this.